# how does String.equals() work

Tags: java, string, equals

I have been trying to understand how some of API methods work

below is a snippet of equals method of java.lang.String class

Can someone out there tell me how actually the code is comparing two strings. 
I get the significance of count, but what does offset signify. how are these variables getting values ?

Like when i create a String. how are these initialized.

a detailed line by line description and also how and when the instance variables, value, count, offset etc are initialized ??

```
 public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
  1014           if (this == anObject) {
  1015               return true;
  1016           }
  1017           if (anObject instanceof String) {
  1018               String anotherString = (String)anObject;
  1019               int n = count;
  1020               if (n == anotherString.count) {
  1021                   char v1[] = value;
  1022                   char v2[] = anotherString.value;
  1023                   int i = offset;
  1024                   int j = anotherString.offset;
  1025                   while (n-- != 0) {
  1026                       if (v1[i++] != v2[j++])
  1027                           return false;
  1028                   }
  1029                   return true;
  1030               }
  1031           }
  1032           return false;
  1033       }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Logically

```
while (n-- != 0) {
if (v1[i++] != v2[j++])
    return false;
}
```

is the same as

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (v1[i] != v2[j])
        return false;
    }
}
```

Why the JVM designers have done it this way I am not sure. Perhaps there is a performance improvement using a while loop than a for loop. It looks quite C like to me so maybe the person who wrote this has a background in c.

`Offset` is used to locate where the string starts within the char array. Internally Strings are stored as char arrays. This is `value`

```
if (v1[i++] != v2[j++])
    return false;
```

checks the characters in the string's underlying char array.

and line by line it is

if the refernce is pointing to the same object is must the equals

```
1014           if (this == anObject) {
1015               return true;
1016           }
```

if the object is a string then check they are equal

```
1017           if (anObject instanceof String) {
```

cast the parameter passed in as String.

```
1018               String anotherString = (String)anObject;
```

remember the length of this.string

```
1019               int n = count;
```

if the two string's lengths match

```
1020               if (n == anotherString.count) {
```

get an array of the characters (value is this array)

```
1021                   char v1[] = value;
1022                   char v2[] = anotherString.value;
```

find out where in this array the string starts

```
1023                   int i = offset;
1024                   int j = anotherString.offset;
```

loop through char array. if the values are different then return false

```
1025                   while (n-- != 0) {
1026                       if (v1[i++] != v2[j++])
1027                           return false;
1028                   }
```

everything else must be true

```
1029                   return true;
1030               }
1031           }
```

if not of type String then they cannot be equals

```
1032           return false;
1033       }
```

To understand offset and value look at the String class

```
/** The value is used for character storage. */
private final char value[];

/** The offset is the first index of the storage that is used. */
private final int offset;

/** The count is the number of characters in the String. */
private final int count;
```

The constructors initialises these variables. The default constructor code is below. You should see something similar for the other constructors.

```
/**
  * Initializes a newly created {@code String} object so that it represents
  * an empty character sequence.  Note that use of this constructor is
  * unnecessary since Strings are immutable.
  */
 public String() {
    this.offset = 0;
    this.count = 0;
    this.value = new char[0];
 }
```

[This](http://illya-keeplearning.blogspot.co.uk/2009/03/java-string-internals.html) is quite a good link to look at

Comment: Thats just so clean.. Thank you.

Comment: One more question, I couldnt find a constructor that is initializing these instance variable. Is there one ? Is this handled by JVM.?

Comment: Just updated the answer with the default ctor for string where these are initialised

Comment: Thanks mate. Excelent answer.

Answer (score 0):

As you may be knowing that string handling in Java is a special case, most of the time the String is assigned from the String pools, so it might be the case that for a char array `"I am Learning Java"`, one string reference points to `"I am Learning Java"`, then offset would be `0`, other string might point to `"am"` so offset would be `2`. **As some of the native code handles its initilization so i think offset is set during that process.(during sharing memory from String pool)**

Also as you can see from the code

```
 public String(String original) {
         int size = original.count;
        char[] originalValue = original.value;
        char[] v;
        if (originalValue.length > size) {
            // The array representing the String is bigger than the new
          // String itself.  Perhaps this constructor is being called
            // in order to trim the baggage, so make a copy of the array.
           int off = original.offset;
          v = Arrays.copyOfRange(originalValue, off, off+size);
        } else {
           // The array representing the String is the same
          // size as the String, so no point in making a copy.
            v = originalValue;
       }
      this.offset = 0;
       this.count = size;
       this.value = v;
    }
```

When new String is created from the old one, it might be the case that old string(original in this case) might be from String pool, thats why first a offset is taken and then the whole array is copied to allocate new memory(new string doesn't share memory from String pool)

Also you should remember String is a derived type and the string is always stored in a character array, so we need an offset to determine from where the string starts in the character array.